# jQuery Mobile fixed footer moves on select list iphone

Tags: ios, cordova, listview, jquery-mobile

I am making a sexual health app as part of a uni project. I have a form which is driving me crazy. I have realised that a common problem in jquery mobile is that fixed footers move to the middle of the page when the keyboard opens, I have fixed this problem with the follow JS

```
//hide footer when input box is on focus
$(document).on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function() {
    $("div[data-role=footer]").hide();
});

//show footer when input is NOT on focus
$(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea, select', function() {
    $("div[data-role=footer]").show();
});
```

This code fixes the problem with the keyboard perfectly, however, on the questions that require a select input from a range of answers (picture link below), as you cycle through with the left arrow key and answer each question the footer moves. The footer does not move is you cycle through and leave the answers at the default "choose one". It is very strange and probably a really easy fix that I don't know about so any help would be really appreciated.

PS. The green bar in the photo is the footer and not the header :P

Image link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x25N.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the onscroll event in your body.
Try it out, I think it's gonna fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply Diego. I have tried researching this but can't seem to understand. Would this be along the right lines? I am only a beginner, sorry. Thanks for the help :)                                                                                                  '$(document).on("scrollstart", 'select', function(){
               $("div[data-role=footer]").hide();
               });

Comment: Let's see, when you get into the page you can record the window.innerHeight and on the scroll, you can detect if it changed. This is one way. in that case I'd do $("body").scroll(function() { if (window.innerHeight < originalHeight) HidDive(); else ShowDiv(); });

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I could not get it work, I then tried this    $("body").scroll(function() {
                 
if (window.innerHeight < originalHeight) {
    $("div[data-role=footer]").hide();
}
                 
else {
    $("div[data-role=footer]").show();
    
}
});                                                                          but still it didn't work